# Как найти аккаунт по id?

Tags: java

Прогрмма записывет счета в `Arraylist`, чтобы потом сделать например операцию пополнения, нужно найти аккаунт в листе по id. Какой метод будет находить аккаунты по `id`?

```java
public class Bank implements BankingOperations, Observable {
    private BankAccount bankAccount;
    private ArrayList<BankAccount> accounts;
    public Bank() {
        accounts = new ArrayList<BankAccount>();
    }
    public boolean hasAccount(BankAccount account) {
        for (BankAccount ba : accounts) {
            if (ba.getNrAccount() == account.getNrAccount()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    // Stream API: anyMatch
    public boolean hasAccountStream(BankAccount account) {
        return accounts.stream().anyMatch(ba -> ba.getNrAccount() == account.getNrAccount());
    }

    public void addAccount(BankAccount e) throws NrAccountEX {
        if (hasAccount(e)) {
            throw new NrAccountEX("Account z takim id juz istieje");
        }
        accounts.add(e);
        System.out.println("Konto: " + e + " Zostało dodane!");
    }

    public void wyswietlListe(){
          for (int i = 0; i<accounts.size(); i++){
              System.out.println(accounts.get(i));
          }
          System.out.println(accounts);
    }


    @Override
    public void deposit(int nrAccount, double amount)throws NrAccountEX, NoMoneyEX {
        if (amount < 0) {
            throw new NoMoneyEX("Kwota musi byc większa od 0!!!!");
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < accounts.size(); i++) {
                if (accounts.get(i).equals(nrAccount)) {
                    accounts.get(i).deposit(amount);
                    System.out.println("Konto numeru: " + nrAccount + " zostało dołądowane o kwote: " + amount + " ,stan konta: " + accounts.get(i).getBalance());
                    if (amount >= 10000) {
                        //+raport
                        notifyObserverOffice(accounts.get(i), amount);
                    }
                } else {
                    throw new NrAccountEX("podaleś nieistniejący numer konta");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void withdraw(int nrAccount, double amount) throws NrAccountEX, NoMoneyEX {
         if (amount < 0){
             throw new NoMoneyEX("Kwota musi byc większa od 0!!!!");
         }else {
             for (int i = 0; i < accounts.size(); i++) {
                 if (accounts.get(i).equals(nrAccount)) {
                     if (accounts.get(i).getBalance() < amount){
                         throw new NoMoneyEX("Twój balance " + accounts.get(i).getBalance()+ "jest mniejszy od kwoty" + amount + "Podaj mniejszą kwotę");
                     }else if (accounts.get(i).getBalance() >= amount) {
                         accounts.get(i).withdraw(amount);
                         System.out.println("Konto numeru: " + nrAccount + " zostało obciazone o kwote: " + amount + " ,stan konta: " + accounts.get(i).getBalance());
                     }
                     if (amount >= 10000) {
                         //+raport
                         notifyObserverOffice(accounts.get(i), amount);
                     }
                 } else {
                     throw new NrAccountEX("podaleś nieistniejący numer konta");
                 }
             }
         }
    }

@Override
public void transfer(int nrAccountFrom, int nrAccountTO, double amount) throws NrAccountEX, NoMoneyEX {
    if (amount <0){
        throw new NoMoneyEX("Kwota musi byc większa od 0!!!!");
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i<accounts.size(); i++){
            if (accounts.get(i).equals(nrAccountFrom) == true){
                if (accounts.get(i).getBalance() < amount){
                    throw new NoMoneyEX("Saldo twojego konta nie pozwala zrobic przelew: balance " + accounts.get(i).getBalance());
                }else if (accounts.get(i).getBalance() >= amount){
                for (int j = 0; j < accounts.size(); j++) {
                    if (accounts.get(j).equals(nrAccountTO)) {
                        accounts.get(i).withdraw(amount);
                        accounts.get(j).deposit(amount);
                        System.out.println("Konto numeru: " + nrAccountFrom + " zostało obciazone o kwote: " + amount + " ,stan konta: " + accounts.get(i).getBalance());
                        System.out.println("Konto numeru: " + nrAccountTO + " zostało dołądowane o kwote: " + amount + " ,stan konta: " + accounts.get(i).getBalance());
                        if (amount >= 10000){
                            //raport
                            notifyObserverOffice(accounts.get(i), amount);
                        }
                    } else {
                        throw new NrAccountEX("Konto na kture chcesz zrobic przelew nie istnieje, podaj prawidlowy numer");
                    }
                }
                }
            }else {
                throw new NrAccountEX("Konto z kturego chcesz zrobic przelew nie istnieje, podaj prawidlowy numer");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Скажите, почему вы посчитали, что **заголовок вопроса** хорошо подходит для большого описания проблемы с большим количеством текста, а не для краткого обозначения проблемы?

Comment: мне 10 символов не хватило чтобы нормально написать, пришлось писать кратко

Comment: @Алексей так нужно в заголовке **кратко** проблему описывать, а не пытаться впихнуть весь текст вопроса туда. Текст вопроса должен быть в самом вопросе, а не в заголовке.

Comment: @Алексей вы не поняли вопроса. зачем в **ЗАГОЛОВОК** впихивать **всё описание проблемы** ? вы же различаете что такое загловок и что такое основной текст?

Comment: Я просто новенький здесь и не знал где писать сам вопрос, теперь знаю

Comment: На самом деле это везде так, на любых ресурсах, блогах, новостях и пр. Заголовок - просто краткое описание.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Следует определить метод, возвращающий счёт из списка по заданному номеру:

```java
public BankAccount getAccountByNumber(int accountNr) throws NrAccountEX {
    for (BankAccount bankAccount : accounts) {
        if (bankAccount.getAccountNr() == accountNr) {
            return bankAccount;
        }
    }
    throw new NrAccountEX("podaleś nieistniejący numer konta");
}
```

Этот метод следует вызывать в `deposit`, `withdraw`, `transfer`:

```java
@Override
public void deposit(int nrAccount, long amount)throws NrAccountEX, NoMoneyEX {
    if (amount < 0) {
        throw new NoMoneyEX("Kwota musi byc większa od 0!!!!");
    }
    BankAccount bankAccount = getAccountByNumber(nrAccount);
    bankAccount.deposit(amount);
    System.out.println("Konto numeru: " + nrAccount + " zostało dołądowane o kwote: " + amount + " ,stan konta: " + bankAccount.getBalance());
    if (amount >= 10_000_00) { // amount in cents/grosz
        //+raport
        notifyObserverOffice(bankAccount, amount);
    }
}

@Override
public void withdraw(int nrAccount, long amount) throws NrAccountEX, NoMoneyEX {
    if (amount < 0) {
        throw new NoMoneyEX("Kwota musi byc większa od 0!!!!");
    }
    BankAccount bankAccount = getAccountByNumber(nrAccount);
    if (bankAccount.getBalance() < amount) {
        throw new NoMoneyEX("Twój balance " + bankAccount.getBalance()+ "jest mniejszy od kwoty" + amount + "Podaj mniejszą kwotę");
    }
    bankAccount.withdraw(amount);
    System.out.println("Konto numeru: " + nrAccount + " zostało obciazone o kwote: " + amount + " ,stan konta: " + bankAccount.getBalance());
    if (amount >= 10_000_00) { // amount in cents/grosz
        //+raport
        notifyObserverOffice(accounts.get(i), amount);
    }
}
```

*Реализация `transfer` должна быть выполнена самостоятельно.*

Особо следует отметить, что `balance`, `amount` должны быть *целочисленными* (`long` или `BigInteger`) и выражать значения с точностью до цента/гроша/копейки, так как арифметика с плавающей точкой (типы `double`/`float`) не является достаточно точной для финансовых вычислений.